# Should i create index on nested _id column in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have nested array of objects with _id inside. I know, that collection has default, top level, index created on _id column. Mu question is - should i create index on nested _id columns or mongodb has a convention that all _id named columns will be indexed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you want you should create an index for nested _id
mongo by default index _id at root level